# Hahn-Banach separation with point on boundary of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I want a separation result as follows; finite dimensions might not matter but is the case of present interest.

Suppose $C\subset \mathbb R^n$ is convex (not necessarily open or closed) and $0\in \partial C$ is in the boundary. Then there is a linear functional $\ell:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ that is non-negative on $C$.

My question is do we need to assume the interior $C^o$ is non-empty? The above result follows in a straightforward way with this assumption from standard classical results: $C^o$ is then a non-empty open convex set, disjoint from the convex set $\{0\}$. Then by a standard Hahn-Banach separation, there is $\ell$ linear functional and real number $\alpha$ such that $$\ell(0)=0\leq \alpha <\ell(x)$$ for all $x \in C^o$. Then by continuity, $\ell\geq 0$ on $\overline{C^o}$, which contains $C$, again if $C^o \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: If $C^\circ$ is empty then $C$ is contained in some hyperplane, so the result is slightly vacuous.

Comment: @copper.hat would you might expanding just a bit on your claims? This is the line along I was thinking however I couldn't tell if it was "cheating" a bit.

Comment: If the affine dimension of $C$ is $n$ then $C$ contains an open set, if not it is contained in a hyperplane.

Comment: (Might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548744/27978 ?)